# Java java.util.Map.Entry and Collection.sort(List,Comparator)

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, comparator

I am doing some execrices in java, I have to read words from file, then
put this words into Map type Hashmap (`word<String,Integer>`) . All it's done .

Next set of pair (type java.util.Map.Entry) , save into List( `List<Entry<String,Integer>>`) and than sort it by Collections.sort(List,Comparator) .
But it doesn't works, cause it says that the sort is not suitable and I havent so much experiences with this sort, can someone help me in this current example how to ? ... thank you for help .

There is part from code:

```
public static void Reader(){

   class Word{
    private String key;     
    private int value;


    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(){
        value=this.value;
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(){
        key=this.key;
    }

    public Word(String key,Integer value){
        this.key= key;
        this.value = value;

    }
    public Word(){

    }

  }

    Map<String, Integer> wordsmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        wordsmap.put("car",2); // wordsmap.put(word as key,frequency as value)
        wordsmap.put("bike",6);
        wordsmap.put("like",1);

       List<Entry<String,Integer>> words = new ArrayList<>(wordsmap.entrySet());

       Collections.sort(words,new Comparator<Word>(){
       public int compare(Word o1,Word o2){
           return o1.getValue() - o2.getValue();
       }

   });
  }


 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Reader();
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: @brianRoach Thank you for time, but I KNOW, that there is java documentation and hundred of examples. I am looking for someone who can explain it on this example,not send the link . But thank you as well.

Comment: Your code doesn't work/make sense. Why do you make a `slova` class that you don't use and a `slova` variable that you do? Why are you using `word1` and the others without ever defining them?

Comment: @nathanielwaisbrot It's mistake with the word1, it means that I will put into map some word with frequency in the text, for example slova.put("car",5) . I will repair it .

With the slova class, I am using getValue() ... but of course, i saw many of examples of comparator and I dont know how to use it with my example so i try some and there was the class slova also .

What to do next to make this comparator works ? Thank you ...

Comment: Your code is still very confused. I recommend talking to an instructor or reading some introductory texts on Java before trying to go any further.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sort a `List<Entry<String, Integer>>` with a `Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>`:

```
Collections.sort(seznam, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>(){
   public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2){
       return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()); // for example
   }
});
```

You haven't indicated how you want to compare the entries: I have compared keys, but you can calculate the comparison how you like.

---

Java 8 update, using a lambda instead of an anonymous class:

```
Collections.sort(seznam, (o1, o2) -> o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()));
```

Comment: @Serġan I added a lambda version (which was not yet available when this answer was posted).

Comment: BTW the question's currently scheduled to be removed as part of the [entry] burnination - should this one be preserved?

Comment: @EJoshuaS It shouldn't have the entry tag, which I have removed.